# iostream, some questions

Tags: c++, iostream

I've seen people do things like....

```
 istringstream ibuf;

 if (ibuf >>  zork >> iA >> Comma >> iB)
```

now I guess the value depends on what >>iB exposes but exactly what is that and what does it mean?  Does true mean all the ietms were extracted?

Also, after an expression like

```
 ibuf >>  zork >> iA >> Comma >> iB;
```

is there any way to find out how many characters and items where extracted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works because of two properties of istream objects:

- istreams return themselves after each extraction (the `>>` operator) to allow chaining multiple extractions (`a >> b >> c`)
- istreams return their status (as though `.good()` were called) when they're cast/converted to bool, via overloading `bool operator !()`

Basically the code you wrote is a short-hand version of:

```
if ( ((((ibuf >> zork) >> ia) >> Comma) >> ib).good() ) {

}
```

Once all the extractions have occured, you're left with `if (ibuf)` which is implicitly like writing `if ((bool)ibuf)`, which checks `ibuf.good()`.

There is no way to get the number of characters extracted over a series of chained extractions, but you can find the number of characters extracted during the last operation with the function [gcount](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/gcount/).  However, it only works for certain format-ignoring functions like `get` and `getline`, and not the extraction operator.

Comment: This is not a cast but an implicit type conversion. Minor nit.

Comment: Is there a technical difference between an "implicit cast" and "implicit conversion"?  Does one imply something the other doesn't?

Comment: If I'm reading http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ correctly it's operator! and operator void* not operator bool. The end result is the same though.

Comment: `bool(stream)` is the same as `!stream.fail()`, which is *different* from `stream.good()`!

Answer (score 1):

The second piece of code reads a set of values from the `ibuf` to the variables following it. However, the return of the hidden `operator >>()` call is an `istringstream` object. There's no direct way to get the character count.

You can check out the `gcount` member function which gives the number of characters for the last *unformatted* input operation. Note that this is per operation, so cascading can't be used. You can also use the `read` member function.

Edit:

```
(ibuf >>  zork >> iA >> Comma >> iB)
```

is actually:

```
((((ibuf.operator >>(zork)).operator >>(iA)).operator >>(Comma)).operator >>(iB))
```

The nesting level of parenthesis tell you the order of calls (and the arguments).

Comment: @dirkgently: Can you tell me more about the "hidden operator"?  Maybe expand my example into a complete parenthesis and show it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ibuf >>  zork >> iA >> Comma >> iB)
```

is logically equal to:

```
ibuf >> zork;
ibuf >> iA;
ibuf >> Comma;
ibuf >> iB;
if (ibuf) ...
```

"is there any way to find out how many characters and items where extracted?"

There is member function "gcount": http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/gcount/

Comment: No, checking `.good()` is not cleaner and actually behaves differently.  Use `if (ibuf)` in the above code.

Comment: You're right.
.good() does only check for error flags (edited).

Comment: You can use the @-syntax so I know you've replied to me, and in this case change the vote; but I happened back here anyway this time. :)

Comment: @Roger Pate: I'm going to remember this. :)